# Portal 2 : Can you switch cross-hair portal color ? (For lefties)

Tags: portal-2

Can I switch Blue and Orange because my mouse have switched button (I'm lefty).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an official option to do this, but you sure can with skins.

Comment: It's cool that you can, but I'm not sure why you would want to do this - don't they have exactly the same properties? (Aside from the colour and the sound effect used...) I use whatever one makes the most sense at the time.

Comment: I switch button in windows (Physical-Left is Software-Right). So in Portal 1/2, My Left button fires the Orange Portal (Right button action). But the visual helper of the cross-hair tell me that Left is blue. So it mix me up in-game.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just change the controls and switch the mouse buttons!  That will make the icon/crosshairs correspond closer to the right buttons without affecting anything else in your system.  Oddly enough you do this through the Keyboard settings:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Haha, just noticed the question was about Portal 2 and not Portal. Glad this can still be done in the new one :P

Comment: I had the same problem in Portal 1, didn't bother to ask..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command `hud_quickinfo_swap 1` and it will switch them around